# How can i save multiple foriegn key value in my table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables. Teacher and student. The teacher table consist with id, name, classid, studentId. In student table consist of id, name, TeacherId.

One student can have more than one teachers. And the teacherid is set as foreign key in student table. Then how can I save my student table with multiple teacherid?

Comment: Show some effort with spacing and capital.  I personally do not answer questions that show not effort.

Answer (score 0):

If a student can have multiple teachers then you can't put the teacher ID in the student table.  You need a third table that contains the combinations of student ID and teacher ID. That way, one student record can be related to multiple teachers and each teacher can be related to multiple students. A third table is how you implement a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate table with student and teacher mapping. So, that a single student id could be mapped with multiple teacher ids and you can also have date range or deactivation columns to change your mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Relationships between entities in relational databases are commonly divided into 3 types. This is called the cardinality of the relationship:

- 1 to N: For example an order (1) with it's products (N). In this case the product would have the order's key.
- 1 to 1: For example a teacher (1) with it's contact info (1). This type of relationships might raise an eyebrown since you *could* put the contact's info inside the teacher's table. In this case either the contact has the teacher's key or the teacher has the contact's key (or both share the same exact key).
- N to M: Like in your case, a particular teacher may have more than 1 student and each of those students might have another teachers. You can't store this relationship in 2 tables (not in a good way at least), so the solution is creating a 3rd table that links the two.

For this last case, you would have something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Teacher (
    TeacherID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Other teacher columns
    )

CREATE TABLE Student (
    StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Other student columns
    )

CREATE TABLE TeacherByStudent (
    TeacherID INT,
    StudentID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (TeacherID, StudentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TeacherID) REFERENCES Teacher (TeacherID),
    FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student (StudentID))
```

Answer (score -1):

Better you should following tables

**Student**

Id (Primary Key)

Name

**Teacher**

Id  (Primary Key)

Name

ClassId (Foreign Key)

**TeacherStudentMapping**

Id  (Primary Key)

StudentId

TeacherId

Set Unique Key for StudentId & TeacherId.